# How to use event dragend markers? Leaflet js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I receive response from server in geoJSON format type POINT. How to add 'dragend' event for marker to see when coordinates change. My attempt:

```
success: function (data) {
  L.geoJSON(data, {
     onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  })
  .on('click', markerOnClick)
  .on('dragend', function(event) {
      console.log('marker is dragged'); 
   })
   .addTo(map)
  },
```

Here in **onEachFeature** depending on the value, i make it draggable or not

```
if (feature.properties.isBlocked == 0) {
   layer.options.draggable = true;
}
else {
   layer.options.draggable = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the listener to the `onEachFeature`:

```
function onEachFeature(feature,layer){
YOUR CODE ...

if (feature.properties.isBlocked == 0) {
   layer.options.draggable = true;
   layer.on('dragend', function(event) {
      console.log('marker is dragged'); 
   })
}
else {
   layer.options.draggable = false;
}
```